# Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations, reference sorted by family name not first name

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, authoryear

I am writing paper using `natbib` package to cite, everything looks fine (I use `cite` command and the result is **author,(year)** in final PDF file) until I add more reference to my `my.bib` file.

suddenly the **author,(year)** turned into numbers **[7]** in my output and got error

*Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers*

Also my reference is sorted by first name alphabetically but in the list I always have family name before first name, which makes it quite confusing when checking the cited paper.

I tried answers from other similar questions:

1)check if new added reference has`,` missing ----no

2)all entries have year-----yes

3)change the `\bibliographystyle`-----not working

4)check conflict commands-------no

**Can someone please give me advise on**

1:get back to **author,(2000)**, get rid of [5] numbers

[image]

2: have cited paper in reference list like below

[image]

currently I have  family initials before first name

[image]

my codes in Latex are

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
%neue Rechtschreibung und Formelsatz
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}


\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\ytl[2]{
    \parbox[b]{8em}{\hfill{\color{cyan}\bfseries\sffamily #1}~$\cdots\cdots$~}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\bullet$}\vrule\quad \parbox[c]{15cm}{\vspace{7pt}\color{red!40!black!80}\raggedright\sffamily #2.\\[7pt]}\\[-3pt]}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

%\usepackage{tablefootnote} % add footnote to a table

%Graphiken
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
%Aufzählungen
\usepackage{paralist}
%Abkürzungen
\usepackage{acronym}
%Tabelle
\usepackage{multirow}
%Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%Fußnotenkram
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.25 cm}



\nocite{*} 
 \bibliography{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE., please post your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX. Can you provide a complete MWE instead of only the lines provided? It makes it easier to track what is happening during compiling the file.